# Demonstration with complex numbers by using conjugates,

Tags: complex-numbers, proof-writing

Let $\text{conj}$ be the complex conjugate. (It makes the following fraction look nicer than $\bar z$.)

So I must demonstrate the following : $$\text{conj} \left( \frac{1}{z} \right) =\frac{1}{\text{conj}(z)}$$

The only part that I don't understand is the conjugate of 1/z. What exactly is the difference when you take the conjugate of the whole fraction compared to taking the conjugate of z only ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conjugate of $a+bi$ is $a - bi$. So, you are being asked to show, given $z$, that the reciprocal of $\text{cong}(z)$ (that is to say, $\frac{1}{\text{cong}(z)}$) is the same as the conjugate of the reciprocal $\text{cong}(1/z)$. (Note this only makes sense if $z\neq 0$.)

To get you started. $z = a + bi$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, and then $\text{cong}(z) = a-bi$. So, $\frac{1}{\text{cong}(z)}= \frac{1}{a-bi}$. Try and express this in the form $c + di$.

Then, also express $\text{cong}(1/z)=\text{cong}(\frac{1}{a+bi})$ in the form $e + fi$.

You must show that $c = e$ and $d = f$.

Comment: OH OK ! I understand how to do it, I got it now. THANK YOU!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30698/discussion-on-answer-by-james-demonstration-with-complex-numbers-by-using-conjug).

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $\text{conj}(z)$ is the reflection of $z$ about the $Re(z)$ axis.

Let $z$ = $Re^{i\theta}$

$$\text{conj}(z) = Re^{i(-\theta)}$$

$$\frac{1}{\text{conj}(z)} = (\text{conj}(z))^{-1} = \frac{1}{R}e^{i\theta}$$

$$\frac{1}{z} =z^{-1} =\frac{1}{R}e^{i(-\theta)}$$

$$\text{conj}\left(\frac {1}{z}\right) = \frac{1}{R}e^{i\theta}$$

$$\therefore \text{conj} \left( \frac{1}{z} \right) =\frac{1}{\text{conj}(z)}$$